# Relationship use difference connection

Tags: php, eloquent

I need to get data from a different database in a relationship, like so:

```
Table1::development(1)->with([ 'column' => function($q) {
    $q->connection('live');
}])->first()
```

`development` is a local scope on my `Table1` model, it just performs a where clause.

I'm getting an error with the above code which I can't figure out:

> Error: BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::connection() in /var/www/vendor/illuminate/database/Query/Builder.php:2445

Can someone help me out?

Comment: i dont think you can use relationship across database connection as Laravel internally creates joins and such. i'd suggest to get the data on another database then use that to filter the other database.

Comment: @BagusTesa if I change the connection on the relationship model this works fine though, however this model is used elsewhere so I can't change the connection globally.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out, not sure if it's the best way. I just added my condition to the construct in my model and then swapped the connection there.

```
/**
     * Create a new Eloquent model instance.
     *
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        parent::__construct();

        if (env('MODE') === 'mode2') {

            $this->setConnection('live');

        }
    }
```